# point size in ggplot 2.0.0

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble recreating a plot since I updated to ggplot version 2.0.0: It seems I can't reduce the point size as much as before, which is a problem in a plot with very many points.
In the below examples, there is a reasonable difference in point size between plot1 and plot2, the point size in plot3 is at least a little bit smaller, but between plot3 and plot4 there's no difference in point size:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=runif(10))
pl <- ggplot(df) +
    geom_point(aes(x,y), size=1)
ggsave("plot1.png", plot=pl, width=14, height=7, units="cm", dpi=1200 )

pl <- ggplot(df) +
    geom_point(aes(x,y), size=0.1)
ggsave("plot2.png", plot=pl, width=14, height=7, units="cm", dpi=1200 )

pl <- ggplot(df) +
geom_point(aes(x,y), size=0.01)
ggsave("plot3.png", plot=pl, width=14, height=7, units="cm", dpi=1200 )

pl <- ggplot(df) +
geom_point(aes(x,y), size=0.001)
ggsave("plot4.png", plot=pl, width=14, height=7, units="cm", dpi=1200 )
```

In the previous version of ggplot2 I had used a point size of 0.25 and it looked way smaller than it does now, which is why I tried to further reduce it using the new ggplot2 version. Do I miss a change in the code of the new version? Couldn't find anything in the documentation...

Comment: In the [ggplot 2.0.0 announcement](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/12/21/ggplot2-2-0-0/) we find that "`geom_point()` now uses shape 19 instead of 16.". I don't know if that's the only change which have affected point appearance.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but couldn't find anything concerning the size

Comment: Interesting - using shape=16 yields much smaller point sizes than the new shape=19, and shape="." is actually a square and not a dot

Comment: If you're worried about having too many points that overlap, you could adjust the transparency using ```alpha```. That might be a good workaround to still see where there are areas of higher density.

Comment: come on...I've just spent one hour trying to recreate a plot I did with the previous version of ggplot2...I'll go with shape=16...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution. As pointed out by @henrik and @silkita now the default shape has changed from 16 to 19 in the latest ggplot2 release. And as you can see in the documentation (for example [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Shapes_and_line_types/)) the shape '19' is slightly larger than '16'. But this is not the reason why "points" are larger in version 2.0.0. Looking at the ggplot2 source of `geom-point.R` for the latest release we can see that:

```
default_aes = aes(
    shape = 19, colour = "black", size = 1.5, fill = NA,
    alpha = NA, stroke = 0.5
  )
```

While in the previous releases it was:

```
default_aes <- function(.) aes(shape=16, colour="black", size=2, fill = NA, alpha = NA)
```

Then, to have the small point as before we should put `stroke` to zero. To summarise, to obtain the smallest point you should write:

```
geom_point(size = 0.1) # ggplot2 before 2.0.0
geom_point(size = 0.1, stroke = 0, shape = 16) # ggplot2 2.0.0
```

By the way, when working with smallest points there is no difference between using different shapes (a pixel remains a pixel).

**UPDATE**: As pointed out on Twitter by Hadley Wickham this change was explained in the [release notes](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/12/21/ggplot2-2-0-0/)

Comment: Good solution. Interesting that they changed it. I would say it was maybe a regression.

Comment: Except when I try it out it does not work. And the documentation you linked claims that `stroke` doesn't even work on `shape=16`.

Comment: Try **size=I(1),stroke=I(0),shape=I(16)**, but I think changing the shape is not significant

Answer (score 27):

Try using the shape parameter:

```
n <- 10000
df <- data.frame(x=1:n, y=runif(n))
pl <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x,y), size=1,shape=".") + labs(title="shape='.',size=1")
pl
```

yields:

[image]

while:

```
pl <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x,y), size=1) + labs(title="size=1")
pl
```

yields: - (and it is the same for all smaller sizes)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, definitely better than before and a good workaround, but I need even smaller points (which I had in the previous ggplot2 version), and would like to really control the point size...

Comment: Yes, I had a similar issue. Should look and see if this is filed as a regression bug yet.

Comment: Looks like this issue still hasn't been fixed more than 5 years later